# How to create a Spark DataFrame from a .txt.bz2 file

Tags: pyspark

How would you create a Spark DataFrame from a .txt.bz2 file called "/datos/cite75_99.txt.bz2" please?

The structure of the source text file is as follows:

```
"CITING","CITED"
3858241,956203
3858241,1324234
3858241,3398406
3858241,3557384
3858241,3634889
```

The desired output is a Spark DataFrame that counts the number of each citing as follows:

```
 +--------+------+
 |NPatente|ncitas|
 +--------+------+
 | 3060453|  3   |
 | 3390168|  6   |
 | 3626542| 18   |
 | 3611507|  5   |
 | 3000113|  4   |
```

Looking forward to your reply.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can Read it directly in spark
Spark supports bz2 compression.

```
%pyspark
df = spark.read.csv(path_to_file)
```